# Riverpod and immutability of a state vs. entites - how to get it right?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

Recently I am learning Riverpod and I get to the idea of an immutable state.

So far so good... except when in many tutorials `entites` were introduced.

Different authors uses terms like:

- model
- entity
- state

For me, my current understanding is (was?):

- model -> a databag without logic/DTO, e.g.:

```
class PersonModel {
  String name = '';
  int age = 0;
}
```

- entity -> a **mutable** object

```
class PersonEntity {
  int id?; // entities are identified by id
  String name = '';
  int age = 0;

  PersonEntity(this.name, this.age);

  // entites have LOGIC
  void changeName(String newName) {...}
}
```

- state -> an immutable object

```
class PersonState {
  final String name;
  final int age;

  PersonState(this.name, this.age);

  PersonState copyWith({String? name, int? age})
  {
    return PersonState(name ?? this.name, age ?? this.age);
  }
}
```

However many (if not all) flutter architecture tutorials treat entities as state/immutable objects transferring it through all layers from Repositories up to state/widgets. (e.g. [here](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-app-architecture-application-layer/))

#### Question:

**Is it normal and correct approach that in Flutter/Riverpod entities are classes without logic and logic is implemented inside Application layer (services)?**

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the actual real things in Flutter-Riverpod are View and State.

When authors try to apply MVC to Flutter-Riverpod they apply labels with some known meaning to Riverpod's `State` that consists of `providers` and `DTOs`.

So, they call `providers` - *controllers*, and `DTOs` - *models*, despite `providers` are not exactly controllers and `DTOs` are not exactly models.

In a typical Flutter app 90% of code belongs to View and 10% to State. So, State-View (or View-State) architecture seems to be very natural and sufficient. Attempts to split State into several layers look artificial and far-fetched.

Comment: Good points. I'll rethink it with my next Flutter project.